# Instantiating XmlSerialization causes breakpoint not being hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

This was a high one on my weird-o-meter. When I uncomment the line creating the *serializer*, the breakpoints **after** it, don't get hit (stay full and red but just are not hit. What can I do to trouble-shoot it?! Of course I understand that the real issue is somewhere else and that I've done something stupid but I simply can't think of anything. Too flabbergasted! When I comment the said line, the breakies are hit like a charm.

```
private static IEnumerable<Mapping> Goat(String path, String param)
{
  XDocument document = XDocument.Load(path);
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Mapping));

  IEnumerable<XElement> chars = document
    .Descendants("Container")
    .Where(element => element.Element("Name").Value == param)
    .Descendants("CharsDataContainer");

  IEnumerable<Mapping> mappings = chars.First()
    .Descendants("DataMapping").Select(element 
      => new Mapping 
      { 
        Key = element.Element("Key").Value
      });
      // => serializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader()) as Mapping);

  int a = mappings.Count();  // Breakpoint here
  return mappings.ToList;    // And here
}
```

I'm not using the deserialization line. And I've added counting and tolisting in order to cause the thing to enumerate and force it to do some breaky-breaky.

What am I missing?!

Comment: If you are running in release mode, `a` is removed. Either use debug mode or use the variable after assignment.

Comment: @leppie Any idea on why I get the expected behavior **without** the serializator being instantiated? I sense that the real issue lies elsewhere. As far I can see, I already run in debug mode and adding any new functionality to the variable won't do me any good...

Comment: The XmlSerializer normally generates code, it could be doing this on another thread that is confusing the debugger. Have you tried, `Debugger.Break();` ?

Comment: @leppie I have not. In fact, I've never used that. Cool. Will try right now.

Comment: I have not. In fact, I've never used that. After having tried that, I got the same misbehavior, so my conclusion is that the instantiation of the serializator plays a voodoo mind trick on the VS. Kind of embarrassing for the IDE, if you ask me. It's really not **that** complex of an expression... I was hoping that there was something more well known that causes the issue...

Comment: Sounds like an exception is being throw and 'silently' caught somewhere then. Turn on catching of all thrown exceptions.

Comment: @leppie Do you mean *Debugging/General* and then *Break when exceptions cross AppDomain...*? I put that on checked but that made me no more wiser.   :)

Comment: No, from the Debug>Exceptions dialog. Tick 'Thrown' IIRC.

Comment: @leppie I don't have that certain option under *Exceptions*, so I checked *Managed Debugging Assistants* and *CLR Exceptions*. **Then** I got something. However, the text was of no use. I can tell it's of no use because parallelly, I've found the issue (mostly thanks to your hint). Apparently, I forgot to add *public* to the class definition of the stupid *Mapping*! Now, can you please summarize the conversation as a reply so we can remove the comments and so I can check your reply as the answer?

Comment: So it was a 'hidden' exception. The menu I am referring to is under the Debug menu (and not under Options). You can post the solution as answer :) (I have enough rep)

Comment: 1. There's no such thing as *too much rep*. One simply goes to heaven when the score is high enough. 2. I went to *Debug* and *Exception* after your suggestion but didn't see any *IIRC* there, just the ones I listed (plus some others, none of which was *IIRC*). Where exactly do you see them? Under which unfoldee? 3. You're just being lazy and don't want to type the reply. I think it's tacky to answer one's own questions but out of respect to a fellow lazy dude, I'll post one. Just for you, mate.   :)